# Can't render an action in base layout and execute it from child template

Tags: symfony

Am working on a Symfony2 application whose among its functions will allow the user to select to visit different sections of the site, and this from anywhere (any page) of the site. For simplifying let's say: when a user want to sort he/she choose from a drop down select form and submit.

I built the action and template with a test root to verify this function and this work (when I use directly the rendering of that sortAction() on my app_dev/test adress.

The issu is that when I try to make this action accessible from the general template (app/Resources/views/base.html) I can view the select form with default view, but when I select for a sort and try to Submit page relaods and return to the defaut view.

I use {% render "MycompanyMybundleBundle:Mycontroller:sort" %} in .../base.html and I want this action to work on (like) mysite/anypage this last extending bundle layout which (layout also extent base).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The description of your problem isn't realy clear, but I think the problem lies at the form action. Do you've configured this action? You should leave it empty if you want to submit it to the same page.

Another solution would be to make use of the extending posibilities of Twig. Define the form as a block in the parent, and override it in the child.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html

EDIT:

You could make the form action a block, that is what I mean...

```
<form action="{% block formAction %}defaulttargetpage.php{ %endblock% }"> <!-- formcontent --> </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think with extend I will need to put {% block form %} {{ parent }} { %endblock% } on each page I create, but me I want the form to work anyway without call it as (like we do for footer or other header components); But I think the first answer could help, because I browse in some tutorial I found that for importing a form submitting on the same page it lies, I have to build 2 templates (one for showing the form, and another for submitting it, and both of these holding-including the same form file).

Thanks for your assistance!